# PowerShell search subfolder with specific file inside

Tags: powershell, filter

I'm looking for an PowerShell command to search a subfolder with specific file inside.
Thanks, Nico

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stack overflow , Please take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt, input and expected output.

Comment: `Get-Childitem "C:\folder123\*" -recurse -include "*.txt"`